# MySQL: Best DB model for a "User referral" system

Tags: mysql

I'm modeling a DB for an application where one of the functions is to get a user from the DB and display in a diagram the selected user and all the referrals of that selected user, and the referrals (if any) for the selected user's referrals, going that way up to 3 referral levels.

I have two theories on how to model a scheme to accomplish this, but I don't know which one is the "best" (in terms of optimization, normalization, etc).

[image: DB Model Candidates]

We have one scheme where the referrals are stored in a different table, with only a BOOLEAN to show if the user is, in fact, referred from another user.

On the other hand, I can substitute the BOOLEAN with a nullable INT (if referred, just store an INT, if null meaning is not referred by anyone).

If there is a better way to accomplish this, suggestions are also welcomed. Thank you.

Comment: SO is not really appropriate for design questions like this. Opinion questions are explicitly listed as being off-topic.

Comment: What is ChildUserID column in Referrals table? Usually it's not safe to store null values in integer field if it is ID kind of thing. I would suggest you keep IsReferred column and if it is true you get referrals from Referrals table. Create constraints for better performance and consistency in data.

Comment: Why are nullable foreign keys bad?

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest a third model. You're talking a model where you can optionally have a referral, so perhaps a table that joins twice to the users table, the first column the refered persons ID, and in the second column, the referring users ID.

Then you know if there is a referral by joining to this table in your queries

Comment: Actually, if I'm not mistaken, that is my 3rd model. I believe it's utterly confusing since I sketched this instead of showing the actual DB. My bad. But thanks a lot for your opinion!

Answer (score 0):

I would use the second design and perhaps add a closure table for easily finding the referrals across multiple levels (see: http://wiki.pentaho.com/display/EAI/Closure+Generator)